# How to remove ' ' on string php inside db query

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-3

i'm new on PHP. I was trying to query to the database like this :

```
...
...
$query.=" AND isnull(try_convert(datetime,a.transactiondate,103),a.createddate) between '? 00:00:00' AND '? 23:59:59'";
$param[]=$dateFrom;
$param[]=$dateTo;

$sql=$this->db->query($query,$param);

return $sql->result_array();
```

and the result query was incorrect and the error was on date near 2021 like this :

```
AND isnull(try_convert(datetime,a.transactiondate,103),a.createddate) 
    between ''2021-01-01' 00:00:00' AND ''2021-11-26' 23:59:59' )
```

I was trying to make a query right from db gui, and the correct query was like this:

```
AND isnull(try_convert(datetime,a.transactiondate,103),a.createddate) 
    between '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-26 23:59:59' )
```

How to remove the `' '` between the date and change from `''2021-01-01' 00:00:00'` to `'2021-01-01 00:00:00'` ?

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` like that. Use explicit `>=` and `<` logic

Comment: Side note, your clause `isnull(try_convert(datetime,a.transactiondate,103),a.createddate)` looks odd. Firstly, why is `transactiondate` *not* a date and time data type? Next, if you need to use logic like that `ISNULL` isn't what you want either; you should be using `OR` logic.

Comment: Question marks inside of quotes will be treated as literal question marks, not placeholders. If you want to use parameter binding, then bind the full datetime. Otherwise, you'll need to use a CONCAT statement

Comment: If you are trying to implement a time-ignorant, inclusive date range, why not convert your timestamps to dates instead of appending time to the date range?

Comment: That 103 looks suspicious.  Are you saving dates as DD/MM/YYYY strings in your database instead of date type data?

Comment: @aynber CI will replace placeholders in quotes -- as shown in the OP's flawed debugging sql text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You can't embed a parameter inside a string, it doesn't use string interpolation. Instead you could use `DATEADD` to add the time.

```php
$query.=" AND isnull(try_convert(datetime, a.transactiondate, 103), a.createddate)
  between ? AND DATEADD(second, 59, DATEADD(minute, 59, DATEADD(hour, 23, ?)))";
```

Or you can add the time on the PHP side.

Note that in any case this is going to get the wrong answer. [You shouldn't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) as you end up missing the last second, instead use half-open intervals `>= AND <`, and add 1 day to the end.

```php
$query.=" 
AND isnull(try_convert(datetime, a.transactiondate, 103), a.createddate) >= ?
AND isnull(try_convert(datetime, a.transactiondate, 103), a.createddate) < ?
";
$param[]=$dateFrom;
$dateTo->modify('+1 day');
$param[]=$dateTo;
```

Comment: Or you can use `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` in the statement.

Comment: Not in SQL Server, that's Postgres I believe